# how can i keep a tree in DB. I need a way with minimum redundancy

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-structures, tree

the Tree has at least 50000 nodes. currently my tree table is:

[image: tree table]

In my application when insert a node, the application will insert records to Tree table to reach ROOT of the tree. for example if insert a node with 200 level distance from the root, it will insert 200 records in the tree table. it is not good. redundancy of this method is too high. anyone can help me?!

ps: a sample tree is like below:

[image: tree example]

Comment: Why do you need to insert more than one record for each node? It seems like your table structure needs to record only the new edge "parent" -> "new node". Each node in a tree has only a single parent (and the path to the root can be found by going up that parent's ancestry). Or maybe I don't understand what "root" means here (not the tree root?)

Comment: But also note that "minimum redundancy" in the way the tree is stored may not be ideal for running queries against the tree. To advise, we need to know what queries you need to run and how often the tree needs to be updated (and in what manner).

Comment: hi dude. yea its root of the tree.

Comment: there is a lot of queries.for example:we need to calculate weight of each node by user request.

Comment: also need to draw tree

Comment: every query is now work so good. but i inserted 10000 node then look at my tree table and see it has more than 500000 records!